# htaccess file protecting but no pass prompt

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

Hi I have the following in a .htaccess file:

AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile /web/clients/.htpasswd
require valid-user

this works in making the directory private, however I get a 403 error and no password/user pop up appears to even give me the chance? Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong, both htaccess and htpasswd are together in the directory I want to protect.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you've checked that already but does the web server have at least read access to the folder you're protecting? If not, this would prevent the htaccess from being read and thus, to password dialog.

Comment: Yes it does have read access.